# np.nditer doesn't assign values when iterates over subarray

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy

Main array doesn't update values during assigning method inside **np.nditer** when iterative array is used as subarray

```py
array = np.arange(20)

with np.nditer(array[np.nonzero(array)],
               op_flags=['readwrite']) as it:
    for x in it:
        x[...] = 5
array
```

> array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19])

---

Subarray assigns great without **np.nditer**

```py
array[np.nonzero(array)] = 5
array
```

> array([0, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5])

---

There is a workaround over by using temporary array.

```py
tmp_array = array[np.nonzero(array)]

array = np.arange(20)

with np.nditer(tmp_array,
               op_flags=['readwrite']) as it:
    for x in it:
        x[...] = 5

array[np.nonzero(array)] = tmp_array
array
```

> array([0, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5])

1. Why main array doesn't update values when **np.nditer** uses subarray assignments?
2. Is there a more convenient way to workaround when subarray assigning in **np.nditer** happens?

Comment: Why are you using `nditer`?  You know how to assign values without iteration.

Comment: @hpaulj I want to learn pros and cons of nditer. Just for study purposes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [48]: arr = np.arange(20) 
    ...: with np.nditer(arr[np.nonzero(arr)], 
    ...:                op_flags=['readwrite']) as it: 
    ...:     for x in it: 
    ...:         x[...] = 5 
    ...: arr                                                                    
Out[48]: 
array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16,
       17, 18, 19])
```

This doesn't change `arr` because it isn't iterating on `arr`.  Instead it is doing:

```
In [49]: arr = np.arange(20) 
    ...: arr1 = arr[np.nonzero(arr)] 
    ...: with np.nditer(arr1, 
    ...:                op_flags=['readwrite']) as it: 
    ...:     for x in it: 
    ...:         x[...] = 5 
    ...: arr1                                                                   
Out[49]: array([5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5])
In [50]: _.shape                                                                
Out[50]: (19,)
```

`arr1` isn't a `view` of `arr`, it is selection, a new array without shared data buffer.

If you want to modify `arr`, you have to iterate on it, not a copy.  Do the test, or anything fancy, inside the loop.

```
In [51]: arr = np.arange(20) 
    ...: with np.nditer(arr, 
    ...:                op_flags=['readwrite']) as it: 
    ...:     for x in it: 
    ...:         if x > 0: 
    ...:             x[...] = 5 
    ...: arr                                                                    
Out[51]: array([0, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5])
```

But why are you using `nditer`?  You already know how to do this kind of selective assignment, using the non-iterative methods:

```
array[np.nonzero(array)] = 5
```

In this case the assignment `=` immediately follows the advanced indexing, and Python uses `array.__setitem__` rather than `arr.__getitem__`.

Iterating on a slice, a `view` does change the source:

```
In [52]: arr = np.arange(20) 
    ...: with np.nditer(arr[5:], 
    ...:                op_flags=['readwrite']) as it: 
    ...:     for x in it: 
    ...:         x[...] = 5 
    ...: arr                                                                    
Out[52]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5])
```

Comment: Can you tell when I have to use nditer? What is the purpose of using np.nditer if it works tremendously slower than selective assignment without non-iterative methods. There is has to be a logic in creating np.nditer but I still cannot find it

Comment: In C level code (e.g. `cython`) it gives a lot of power, especially when working with multiple inputs.  See the end of the iteration tutorial page.  The Python level interface is mainly useful for testing ideas for that port.  The docs need a stronger disclaimer.